# Kali linux laptop lock screen

Tags: process, kali-linux, screen-lock

Now I am trying to hack my router password, and I want to ask if I lock my laptop, the hacking procces still goes on? or I need to have my screen on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The locking of the screen does not interrupt any started processes. You should be fine.